# joomla! 1.5.26 and "You are currently logged in to the private area of this site"

Tags: joomla1.5

When the Joomla! (1.5.26) session has expired, I redo the login, after submitting username and password I get this message: "You are currently logged in to the private area of this site." 
If I click on another internal-link the redirection works, but if I re-click on the same return url link (where I was where the session has expired) I re obtain the previous message, but I'm logged in correctly!
I use the Joomla! SEF. No other external component/module/plugin.

To make it running I have to delete manually the browser's cache!

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After months I got it!!!
Joomla! 1.5.26 line 324 in the file /libraries/joomla/application/application.php
Comment the following lines

```
/*
if (!$moved && strstr(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), 'webkit') !== false) {
    // WebKit browser - Do not use 303, as it causes subresources reload (https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38690)
    echo '<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;'. $url .'" /></head><body></body></html>';
}
else {
    // All other browsers, use the more efficient HTTP header method
    header($moved ? 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently' : 'HTTP/1.1 303 See other');
    header('Location: '.$url);
}
*/
```

And leave only

```
// All other browsers, use the more efficient HTTP header method
header($moved ? 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently' : 'HTTP/1.1 303 See other');
header('Location: '.$url);
```

The webkit bug has been resolved. Check here: [Bug 38690 - Submitting a POST that leads to a server redirect causes all cached items to redownload](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38690)

Answer (score 2):

Just had this happen to me, and remembered seeing your question.  I don't know what your SEF ramifications are, but in my case, the native Joomla url works "normally":

`http://mysite.com/?option=com_mycomponent&view=myview&Itemid=48`

When I inadvertently excluded "view" like below, it gave me the same result as you're experiencing:

`http://mysite.com/?option=com_nmm&Itemid=48`

This suggests to me that your SEF is translating the friendly url into an invalid Joomla url.  Hope this helps!  Joomla *knows* you're logged in, but is missing all the info it needs to display whatever it is that you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! If I set the session (DB) lifetime to 1 min the bug happens. I use the Joomla! SEF and the page is called in this way http://website.com/page.html?view=mycomponent. Following another link I tried to set the Joomla! cache_handler option like  var $cache_handler = 'apc'; but the bug still exists. I'm still trying to solve it.

Comment: Bug behavior: 1)The Joomla! session has expired; 2) Click on a menu link the page is redirected to the login page (index.php?option=com_user&view=login&return=aHR0cDovL2Rldi1lZmFzLWlzLmllcy5qcmMuaXQvaG9tZS5odG1s); 3)I insert username/password and the redirection to the last visited page doesn't work anymore and the message appears, but I'm able to see all the other pages. Ideas?

Comment: Wish I could help more....I'd be pulling out my debugging toolkit at this point to find the answer, but can't do that for your code. :(

Comment: It happens only using Chrome. Using FF 13.0.X and IE8> works.