# joomla! 1.5 auto redirect to home page instead of login page when the session expires

Tags: joomla1.5, session-timeout

In Joomla! 1.5, when the user's session has expired the application should redirect to the home page.
Currently, it's redirected to the login page. 
How to do this? Which file do I have to modify?
Thanks!

Comment: I have add the same question but I didn't get any answer... Did you find anything?

Comment: I solved changing the core code. Have a loot at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244439/joomla-1-5-26-and-you-are-currently-logged-in-to-the-private-area-of-this-site/12244551. But I really don't remember if this is your solution. Just inform me here. I will have a deeper look at the code

Comment: Now I got what your question is about!!! You had this as an issue right? What I want to do is to find how can I set my own redirect page when user's session expires!!! Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: It was a combination of errors. I solved your issue doing so: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2111127